# equivalence of two definitions of differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have two definitions and I want to understand why they are equivalent. 
1. Def.: Consider $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ a function. f is called differentiable of class $C^k$, if all the partial derivatives $\frac{d^t}{dx^t}$ exist up to order k and they are continuous. 
2.Def.: $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ a function. f is differentiable if the derivative exists and the $b_i$ are continuous, with $b_i=\frac{d}{dx_i}(p)$. The derivate of f is an affine function $L_p:U\to \mathbb{R}$ $x\mapsto c+\sum_{i=1}^nb_ix_i$, such that $L_p(p)=f(p)$ and $\lim_{x\to p}\frac{|f(x)-L_p(x)|}{\|x-p\|}=0$. 
In the last quotient, it has to be $L_p(p)$? And are this definitions equivalent if f is differentiable of class $C^1$ (i think)?
To prove the second definition, I have to define such a map $L_p$, $p\in U$, as you can see in 2.Def., the derivatives $\frac{d}{dx_i}$ exist if I assume 1. And then I have to show the properties of $L_p$ as stated in 2?

 For 2.=>1. There is nothing to do...?
Regards